# URL Rewrite Pattern for my URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis-7.5

I'm using URL rewrite module, but i do not know how to apply a pattern for my requirement, please help

My URLs are :

mychick.com/Cat/Prod/chicken-skin-clean.html
& 
mychick.com/Cat/Prod/chicken-head-crown.html

I need this URL should be rewritten to

mychick.com/Cat/Prod/chicken-skin-clean
mychick.com/Cat/Prod/chicken-head-crown

**I need a single pattern to rewrite these two URLS**

Comment: Are you using Apache Module mod_rewrite?

Comment: I installed microsoft URL rewrite module and using IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

if you looking doing it in java , you can split it by ".html"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="mychick.com/Cat/Prod/chicken-skin-clean.html";
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s.split(".html")[0]);

    }
```

on output you have

```
"mychick.com/Cat/Prod/chicken-skin-clean.html"
"mychick.com/Cat/Prod/chicken-skin-clean"
```

bet, it can be done better and its only works to cut .html, but you asked for it.
problem will by if in url is syntax to cut, but if so, you can join tab elements from 0 to lenght-1 and puting back ".html" between strings